# Remove PostID on Tumblr Theme

Tags: html, css, themes, tumblr

I'm trying to learn how to make my own Tumblr theme following their documentation http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes.

There is a number (or {PostID} as the documentation describes it) on each post that I don't want.

I think it has something to do with the `<ol id="post"> ... </ol>` around the posts but if I remove it or change it to  `<div class="posts"> ... </div>` it just turns into bullet points.

Does anyone know how to remove the numbers or bullet points completely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few bits here and there that are a little more advanced than you need to delve into right now but the most of it is basic HTML.

You can change the templates but unfortunately the post ID has to stay ..it's built in.

You can find more info here; https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28049/changing-messy-tumblr-url

Good luck with the template.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

When you changed `ol` to `div`, did you change the children, too?

The `ol` element is a list which contains `li` elements, which are list items, and typically displayed as bullet points.

If you want to remove the display of the `ol`, use CSS. For example: `ol#post li {list-style-type: none;}`.

If you want to change the HTML element (e.g., from `ol` to `div`), make sure that you also change the `li` elements (e.g., also to `div`).

If you want to remove the post ID (which is displayed somewhere on your site), edit your theme and remove `{PostID}`.